# scala add _2 s in a list of Tuple 2

Tags: scala

I have the following mutable Hashmap in Scala:

```
HashMap((b,3), (c,4), (a,8), (a,2))
```

and need to be converted to the following:

```
HashMap((b,3), (c,4), (a,10))
```

I need something like reduceByKey function logic.

I added the code here

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val m = new mutable.HashMap[String,Tuple2[String,Int]]()
    println("Hello, world")
    m.+=(("xx",("a",2)))
    m.+=(("uu",("b",3)))
    m.+=(("zz",("a",8)))
    m.+=(("yy",("c",4)))

    println(m.values)
  }
```

Comment: Keys in a hashmap are unique, so you do not have that mutable hashmap. By the time you've put those keys into a hashmap, you've already lost the older of them. Where do you get this data from? Can you get it as, perhaps, a list of tuples or something that allows duplicates?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use a `groupMapReduce` before?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I added the code and that was my output of println.

Comment: What purpose do the keys in the hashmap serve in your code example? It looks like you're grouping by a part of the value, not by the key? Is there any significance to the `xx`, `yy`, etc. part, or can we just get rid of that?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Hi. I need to implement it in pure scala 2 .

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It has a concept in my app. But for this time, I just want to group values by it's key (i.e. `a`,`b`,`c` not `xx` or `yy`). I want to drop keys of first hashmap (i.e. `m`).

Comment: `m.values.groupMapReduce(tuple => tuple._1)(tuple => tuple._2)((a, b) => a + b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pre 2.13 Scala versions you can try using `groupBy` with `map`:

```scala
m.values
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you have is not a hashmap but `m.values` of type `Iterable[Tuple2[String, Int]]`, which is more manageable. In that case, as hinted at in the comments, [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/collection/IterableOps.html#groupMapReduce%5BK,B%5D(key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BK,B%5D) does it all in one function. This function groups "matching" elements together, applies a transformation to each element, and then reduces the groups using a binary operation.

```
m.values.groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_ + _)
```

This says "Group the values by the first element of their tuple, then keep the second element (i.e. the number), and then add all of the numbers in each group". This produces a map from the first element of the tuple to the sum.

```
Map(a -> 10, b -> 3, c -> 4)
```

Note that this is a `Map`, not necessarily a `HashMap`. If you want a `HashMap` (i.e. for mutability), you'll need to convert it yourself.

Comment: I used Scala 2 and `groupMapReduce` cannot be resolved by compiler.

Comment: @MajidHajibaba `groupMapReduce` was introduced in Scala 2 =)